# Unable to create shared library due to 'No such file or directory'

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I am trying to combine two files `foo.c` and `bar.c` into a dynamically-linked library `foobar.so`. I am using the command:

`gcc -shared foobar.so foo.c bar.c`

But I am getting the error:

`gcc: error: foobar.so: No such file or directory`

`foo.c` and `bar.c` both contain a single function definition and that's it. There are no other files in the directory.

Comment: You can find the command-line options documented in [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html#Invoking-GCC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass output file name with -o option:

```
gcc -shared -o foobar.so foo.c bar.c
```

Otherwise gcc will think that foobar.so is also an input file.

Comment: thank-you, it appears the tutorial i was following was wrong